# How do I use a substitution directive with an abbreviation in Sphinx (reST)?

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I'm trying to automate abbreviations in my Sphinx documentation using substitutions and abbreviations in conjunction like below:

```
.. |CFD| :abbr:`CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics)`
```

I get the error:

```
Substitution definition "CFD" empty or invalid.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted `replace::` in your reStructuredText markup. This should work.

```
.. |CFD| replace:: :abbr:`CFD (Computational Fluid Dynamics)`
```